# I just can't get my head around the concept as how , if some algorithm's time complexity is O(n^2) then it is also O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Like in these notes : [image: Images are from notes provided by an famous Indian youtuber]

I am new in DS and Algorithms , I have tried searching this topic on google and youtube , but no satisfying answer in simple words. If some example is provided , it will really be helpful .

[image]

Comment: Sorry , one picture regarding the question , didn't get uploaded . So , was uploading it .

Comment: Mm. I mean it makes no sense to me, I think that statement is wrong.

Comment: That statement is backwards. Most likely a typo.

Comment: Good job tho! Being confused because something is wrong is a sign you're actually learning rather than just memorizing and repeating.

Comment: If this section was about big Omega, then probably that last sentence should be Omega and not O? Then it would also be correct.